# Chrome extension: posting to an existing tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

simple question about the ability of chrome extensions. 
Is it possible to for example hit an extension button and write the url (or other content of a page) to an endpoint of a open tab. For example, tab 1 is a web application that gathers bookmarks (so not locally stored) and if I hit a button in tab 3 I want to make a POST call to tab 1. Or can something like this be achieved by storing information in the Chrome storage which can then be read by the application in tab 1?

So quite simply:

tab 1 (:web application) - gets POST request -> tab 3 (:just a web page) through the click of a button of an active extension. I know if this would exist it could lead to some security issues, hence the question.

Comment: Why specifically POST request? Can you give more details?

Comment: do you mean you want to send message from tab3 to tab1 ?

Comment: Well for example, say a web CRM is tab 1, and it provides an endpoint which you can POST to, and tab 4 is a webpage that you want to add to the CRM. Is it possible to perform a POST request to tab 1 with the click of button in Chrome passing the url of tab 4 for example. Hope that clarifies it.